# How small could an advanced sapient species be?

Tags: science-based, biology

Tiny sapient species are a staple of both sci-fi and fantasy, with both faeries and who-like races that live on dust specks found across the pages of various books. We've even had some excellent questions about them, like [this one about armed sparrows.](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/9529/what-would-a-sentient-intelligent-but-very-small-bird-use-as-a-ranged-weapon-a) In reality, however, it seems as though there should be limits in terms of size that set a lower boundary on how big something can be and still be sapient. Below this size, a species would simply not have enough neurons to be able to form a brain that is capable of abstract manipulation of concepts. What would this size be, and what factors, such as chemical composition or structure of a life form, might influence it?

By a sapient species, I specifically mean a species capable of the types of thought that would allow for the development of things like advanced technology. The species need not necessarily have a human-like experience of reality.

Comment: I'm not certain we can give an exact answer here.  We know how *our* neurons work (kind of), but that doesn't mean it's the only source of sentience.  If, for example, we can make sentient AI it's 'brains' would fit on a micro computer the size of a chip potentially.  Did you want to limit the question to standard human-like brain and evolution?

Comment: Possible dupe of: [What is the Smallest Sentient Species Possible?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/what-is-the-smallest-sentient-being-possible) and [Minimum Brain Size for Consciousness?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/7031/minimum-brain-size-for-consciousness)

Comment: Also, I assume you are actually asking about *sapient* beings, not sentient?  Sentient means aware, and most animals are.  Sapience means actual human-like intellect and ability to think and reason.  Is it safe to assume you actually are interested in the later, or are you interested in mere sentient?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/12937/6986), which is marked a duplicate of [this](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/7031/6986).

Comment: @DustinJackson Yay for delays.

Comment: Note the brain doesn't need to be local. Your species could develop "remote-controlled organs", so that a relatively big brain controls insect-sized organisms, able to see through their eyes and use their limbs. You'd need to develop a "wireless neurotransmission" for that to work, but that's not really impossible.

Comment: I'm disappointed that the two questions got merged. Human brain comprises about 2% of human body weight and there are countless factors that could scale the body down a whole lot without reducing the brain size.